# MongoDb partial filter expression not working

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a `CompoundIndex` which has 2 field for unique and i want to filter the index to accept null as not unique.

Below is my code
`@CompoundIndex(def = "{'studentId':1, 'StudentName':1}", unique = true, partialFilter = "{'studentId': { 'ne' : null } }")`

now when i am trying to save the student with same id and name which already exists it is not throwing me error.

Comment: You need a dollar sign before `ne` as in `$ne`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$ne` query operator is not allowed in a partial filter expression, see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-partial/#create-a-partial-index

Use `{'$exists':true}` instead of `{ 'ne' : null }` if you only need to test if the field exists.

If you also want to exclude documents where the field was explicitly set to null, use:

`{'studentId':{'$exists':true,'$gt':null}}`